# Apache Storm Logging Custom Encoder

Tags: java, logstash, apache-storm

In my web apps, etc I use logstash for log file collection, and the great logstash encoder to format my logs as json, making them easy/fast to injest to logstash, and allowing the use of markers to record fields, etc.  In apache storm which has its own logback config, I'm having trouble getting this encoder working.  I added the required jars to the $STORM_DIR/lib as per the logstash-logback-encoder directions on its wiki, and added this to the cluster.xml:

On startup, a process list shows that the jar is in the classpath, but storm stops logging.. Anyone see or solve this before?

Comment: Can you post your logback configuration and your storm.yaml? It can probably be solved within these two files.

Comment: You forgot to post your `cluster.xml` file.